# How to tally occurrences of same value across columns in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, logic, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe like so:

| exit | x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 4 | 6 | 6 | NA |
| 4 | 4 | 6 | 6 | NA |
| 5 | 4 | 6 | 6 | NA |
| 6 | 4 | 6 | 6 | NA |

I am only interested when `exit = xi`, where `i = 1, 2, 3, 4` as shown in the data. I want to count the number of times `exit = xi`. So, the ideal output I am looking for is:

| exit | x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 | n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 4 | 6 | 6 | NA | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 6 | 6 | NA | 1 |
| 5 | 4 | 6 | 6 | NA | 0 |
| 6 | 4 | 6 | 6 | NA | 2 |

Ideally I would like to be using `ifelse()` in R, but it seems I am unable to figure out a good logical path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution using base R:

```
df <- data.table::fread("
exit    x1  x2  x3  x4
3   4   6   6   NA
4   4   6   6   NA
5   4   6   6   NA
6   4   6   6   NA
")

df[, n := rowSums(apply(df, 2, function(col)
    col == df[, exit])[, -1], na.rm = T)]

> df
   exit x1 x2 x3 x4 n
1:    3  4  6  6 NA 0
2:    4  4  6  6 NA 1
3:    5  4  6  6 NA 0
4:    6  4  6  6 NA 2
```

Note that if you explicitly wish to use `ifelse()`, there are several possibilities to do that. A simple modification of the provided solution above would be

```
df[, n := rowSums(apply(df, 2, function(col)
    ifelse(col == df[, exit], 1, 0))[, -1], na.rm = T)]
```